# E138: can't write to viminfo file C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\_viminfo！

Tags: windows, vim

E138: can't  write to viminfo file C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile_viminfo！

but I don't find the file from C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile_viminfo！ It also can't find .viminf*.tmp anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are launching gvim via a taskbar shortcut you end up using system32 as what would usually be expected as a user's home folder.  To check, right-click the taskbar vim icon and go to properties and see where it is launching from.

You may want to manually set it to your user directory.  THEN things like viminfo _vimrc etc work as expected.

Also, remember that .vimrc (with the dot) is what the file is in unix or mac but use underscore for windows : _vimrc.  I would assume that this behavior would carry over to other files as well, ie. viminfo.  The underscore is the hiding char equivalent to the dot -- I think...  it's been a while since I the windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an auth issue. Try creating `$HOME/_viminfo` manually.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer here is correct.
[Changing Vim Home Directory](https://superuser.com/questions/346093/changing-vim-home-directory)

Turns out all I had to do was set the HOME environment variable.
I set it to the same as ~

so in your powershell $profile file (if that's is your thing)

```
cd ~
$env:HOME = Get-Location
```